# Proof question about supremums and maximums.

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

> Let S be a nonempty bounded subset of $\Re$ and let $m=supS$. Prove that $m\in S$ iff $m = maxS$.

Here's my proof:

Let $S \subseteq \Re$ be nonempty and let $m=supS$.

Suppose $m \in S $. Since S is bounded, we have S has an upper bound, specifically $m$ which is the least upper bound. Since $m \in S$, that must mean $m = maxS$.

On the other hand, suppose $m = maxS$. This, by definition, implies that $m$ is the least upper bound and $m \in S$.

Q.E.D.

Is this proof correct?

Comment: Your last statement has to be proved. You need to make an argument which suggests that $\forall s \in S \left( s \leq m \right)$ so that $m$ is the maximum. However, your idea is correct. Writing can be imporved!

For second part, you need to show that any element less than $m$ cannot be an upper bound, so that $m$ is the "least" upper bound.

Comment: Thank you so much for the feedback. I see what you mean now that I’m reading it over.

Comment: For both directions, you need to recall the definition of supremum and maximum.